# How do I change the size of a VHD?

Tags: vhd

I have a fixed size virtual hard drive that is running out of space. What's a good way to go about increasing the size?

This VHD is created from Microsoft Virtual PC and/or Microsoft Virtual Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a free utility you can download called [VHD Resizer](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry87.aspx) that should simplify this task.

There is also a [step-by-step walkthrough](http://kb.dutchalps.com/microsoftvirtualpc.htm) of the entire process that might be of help.

Comment: Also interested in a free "dir" tool? No need and thus sense in using external tools for what MS does itself.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the /extend switch of Microsoft's [VHD Tool](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vhdtool).

> VHD tool is an unmanaged code
>   command-line tool which provides
>   useful VHD manipulation functions
>   including instant creation of large
>   fixed-size VHDs. The source code is
>   included.

Usage:

```
VhdTool.exe /create <FileName> <Size> [/quiet]
VhdTool.exe /convert <FileName> [/quiet]
VhdTool.exe /extend <FileName> <NewSize> [/quiet]

Create: Creates a new fixed format VHD of size <Size>.
        WARNING - this function is admin only and bypasses
        file system security.  The resulting VHD file will
        contain data which currently exists on the physical disk.

Convert: Converts an existing RAW disk image file to a fixed-format VHD.
         The existing file length, rounded up, will contain block data
         A VHD footer is appended to the current end of file.

Extend: Extends an existing fixed format VHD to a larger size <Size>.
         WARNING - this function is admin only and bypasses
         file system security.  The resulting VHD file will
         contain data which currently exists on the physical disk.
```