# Changing maximum file size of vhds

Tags: virtualization, vhd

I am native booting into vhd files. While creating the parent vhd file I set the maximum file size to 50GB however I never install so many applications. 20GB maximum will be enough for me but I want to change this setting on existing parent vhd file as I don't want to go through installing the OS from scratch into a new vhd. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the size of a VHD?](http://serverfault.com/questions/6139/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-a-vhd)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not trying to make the disk larger. When you native boot to a vhd, vhd file is automatically expanded to the size you specify when creating the disk. So my disk is expanded to 50GB automatically. I am trying to make it smaller. Not larger.

Comment: Bigger and smaller are the same process. Don't forget the reduce the size of the partitions on the disk before shrinking the actual disk.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible:

see: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vhdtool

and

[How do I change the size of a VHD?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6139/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-a-vhd)

Comment: Please see my above comment. This is not I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is [**this**](http://tech-informer.com/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-vhd-files-in-virtual-pc-225/) what your looking for ?

There's more [**here**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=&q=how+to+decrease+the+size+of+vhd+files&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enGB283GB283&ie=UTF-8) too.

Comment: Not exactly. I am not using virtual pc. I am using native boot and only trying to change MAXIMUM file size setting so it doesn't expand automatically to 50GB.

Comment: This is what you're looking for. VHDs can not be resized while in use. You'll have to edit the file with another OS, then boot into it again.

Answer (score 0):

if you plan to utilize this server for long then 20gigs won't be big enough due to issues with the winsxs growth..  Other then that you need to mount the physical disk to another w2k8r2 or win7 device then mount the vhd then run the vhd resizer tool!  Or if you have multiple boot selections boot to another os then mount the vhd file then resize.